# How can I prepend a line number and tab to each line of a text file?

Tags: unix, bash

How can I append a line number and tab to the beginning of each line of a text file?

Comment: What I'm wondering is how you'd do it on Windows...

Comment: Should this be on stackoverflow?
For superuser the answer is Notepad & lots of patience.

Comment: So, do you want to prepend or append. Your title and body texts are different ;)

Comment: I guess I want to *append to the beginning*, "prepend" being only a word to hackers.

Comment: On Windows, as with any other programming-ish question, you could install Cygwin and then use the answers below.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
awk '{printf "%d\t%s\n", NR, $0}' < filename
```

Comment: Or `awk '{print NR, "\t", $0}'`.

Comment: answer below, with nl command line, is a much simpler solution.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro simpler but less reliable and less flexible.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro The answer using `nl` is also WRONG. In source code, it will never give you the right line numbers, as it doesn't count lines with only whitespace.

Comment: @jtbandes Your solution adds spaces between the line number and tab (at least on my mac)

Answer (score 63):

The nl command should do this, but it adds space before the line number too. It's part of Linux coreutils.

```
nl lines.txt
 1  $bkWTN
 2  $cV8$.
```

Comment: Actually, you can tell `nl` to omit the space before the number.  Just use the `-w1` option to tell it the minimum width for a number is 1.

Comment: Beware that 'nl' assumes by default that your text is split into 'pages' with headers and footers, all delimited by lines like '\:' or '\:\:' or '\:\:\:'. If your text has any lines like this in it, then 'nl' will produce unexpected results, such as swallowing those lines, sections with no numbering, or restarting the numbering from 1 in a section. Use -dXY (where XY is a pair of characters that do not occur on a line by themselves in your text) to prevent this behaviour. In the general case, this might be hard to predict, so I'd recommend using one of the other solutions on this page.

Comment: Using '-w1' will not just remove the space after the numbers, but will also *truncate* the line numbers to only be one character wide, meaning your lines numbers only display their least significant digit. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: With `-nln` you can left-justify if you don't want the space(s) before line numbers. Also, to specify a tab separator you could use `-s$'\t'` or `-s'    '` (insert a tab between the single quotes with `ctrl+v` then `tab`).

Comment: @JonathanHartley `nl -w1` (from GNU coreutils 8.24) does *not* truncate the line numbers.

Comment: This is wrong. It skips/doesn't count lines composed of line numbers. The accepted answer works.

Answer (score 10):

```
sed = test.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/'
```

The `sed =` command will print the line number followed by a carriage return and then the next line.

The expression "N;s/\n/\t/" will take each line, get the next line (i.e. line number and the line), and replace the carriage return with a tab.

Comment: Prints a "t" with no tab with my version of sed:

8t I saw the best minds of my generation destroyed by
9t madness, starving hysterical naked,

Comment: Note that `\n` is line feed (commonly called just "newline", since its first widespread usage was in Unix), and `\r` is carriage return. Windows uses `\r\n` (also referred to as `CRLF`).

Comment: (Yay nitpicking!)

Comment: If we're going to get into nitpicking about how windows might be different, then we might need to consider UTF16.

Answer (score 5):

```
cat -n <yourfile> | perl -pe "s/^\s*(\d+)\s+/\1\t/"
```

cat -n adds linenumbers as "   123  linecontents" and that regexp modifies it to "linenumberTABlinecontents"

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe "s/^/$.\t$_/" file.txt
```

or

```
perl -ne "print qq($.\t$_)" file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
cat -n somefile.txt
```

?

Comment: No tab. (Comments needing 15 chars is a stupid requirement.)

Comment: This produces tabs on my system. cat (GNU coreutils) 6.10.

Comment: On my system, it adds (tab)number(space)line.  BSD Utils.

Answer (score 2):

OK, Here's a one-line bash solution:

```
$ IFS=$'\n';x=1;for l in $(<file.txt);do echo -e "$x\t$l";((x+=1));done
$ IFS=
```

The first IFS setting tells bash to read a full line at a time.
The second line resets the IFS to default.

As an added bonus, it runs completely in your shell and doesn't exec a program!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed file.txt -e 's/^/\t/' | cat -n | sed -e 's/^\t//'
```

or for some non-GNU `sed`s:

```
cat file.txt | sed -e 's/^/\\t/' | cat -n | sed -e 's/^\\t//'
```

Comment: Prints a "t" with no tab with my version of sed.

Comment: Edited to double-escape; try it like that.

Comment: If all else fails, just hit tab. :)  (Or ^V tab if your shell gives you trouble with that.)

Comment: sed: 1: "test.txt": undefined label 'est.txt'

Comment: 'cat test.txt | sed -e 's/^/\\t/' | cat -n' prints (tab)number(space)\t(line)

Comment: Okay, two versions, second one for your `sed`, both getting rid of the leading tab `cat -n` likes.

Comment: Just an aside, my sed isn't old.  It's just not GNU.  :)

Comment: Duly noted, edited per. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since we are collecting ways to do this,

```
 grep -n . file.txt | sed 's/\(^[0-9]*\):/\1    /g'
 # this is a tab with Ctrl-V + Tab  =====>  ----
```

Comment: Now I see this. OK, delete my own post. What? You say that SU doesn't let you delete your own post?

Comment: grep + sed == awk